# Kohana 3.2 relationship - Joins

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2, kohana-db

i have the current design in mysql :

Table **filesubject**
[image]

Is there a way in Kohana to set relationship in a way that if i make something like

ORM::factory('filesubject')->where('file_id','=',$file->id)->find_all()->as_array());

That i get all the joins from the other tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your question. To automatically join models, first setup your relationships ($_belongs_to etc) and then look at:

In your model:

```
ORM property: $_load_with. eg: protected $_load_with= array(model1, model2, etc)
```

Or at run time:

```
ORM method: with(). eg: ORM::factory('filesubject')->with('model')->with('model2')->find_all()
```

I don't think the as_array() function pulls in the joined data though. Once it's actually performing the join you'd need to overwrite as_array (or write your own function) to output the nested key/pair values from the joined properties.

Comment: yes this is what i'm asking about (the as_array after doing the relationships) is there any method in kohana that returns the results or i'll have to process it my self ?

Comment: found the answer here : http://www.geekgumbo.com/2011/05/24/kohana-3-orm-a-working-example/  Thank for your help :)